# Dynamic Workload Console doesn't work whit Firefox esr 45.5 with IBMCCK 2.3.0 (CCK2)

Tags: workload-scheduler

When monitoring workload with the Dynamic Workload Console, the result table appears to be empty if using Firefox esr 45.5 with IBMCCK 2.3.0 (CCK2). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, use a different browser or upgrade Firefox to esr 45.